# Import sql file to ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, jdbc

I'd like to import data from a sql file to ElasticSearch. I know the way via JBDC and Logstash but it requires the data to be loaded into mysql at first. Since the sql file is rather huge, I'd like to skip this part and import directly. Is there a possibility to do this?

EDIT:
I've stumbled across this solution but maybe there's an easier way:
[Link](http://david.pilato.fr/blog/2015/09/14/import-from-sql-without-database/)

Comment: Happy you found my blog post :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm posting here [the blog post content](http://david.pilato.fr/blog/2015/09/14/import-from-sql-without-database/) I wrote in 2015 so it might be a bit outdated (specifically the elasticsearch part - mapping and logstash elasticsearch output: was designed for elasticsearch 1.7) but still valid in the approach.

---

Recently, I got a database MySQL dump and I was thinking of importing it into elasticsearch.

The first idea which pops up was:

- install MySQL
- import the database
- read the database with Logstash and import into elasticsearch
- drop the database
- uninstall MySQL

Well. I found that some of the steps are really not needed.

I can actually use [Elastic stack](https://www.elastic.co/products) and create a simple recipe which can be used to import SQL dump scripts without needing to actually load the data to a database and then read it again from the database.

## Parsing SQL script with logstash

I exported some data from a MySQL example database I have. You can download the same [data](https://gist.github.com/dadoonet/2e83d126e5a5666598b1).

### SQL Insert script

Our objects are split on 3 tables but we are not going to do joins here. We will only import data from `Person` table.

Let's look at the important lines of the script:

```
--
-- Table structure for table `Person`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Person`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `Person` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `children` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dateOfBirth` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `gender` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `reference` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `address_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `marketing_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FK_tagx64iglr1dxpalbgothv83r` (`address_id`),
  KEY `FK_j4ifv49erkwul9jruu15o40r4` (`marketing_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_j4ifv49erkwul9jruu15o40r4` FOREIGN KEY (`marketing_id`) REFERENCES `Marketing` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_tagx64iglr1dxpalbgothv83r` FOREIGN KEY (`address_id`) REFERENCES `Address` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=10001 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Dumping data for table `Person`
--

LOCK TABLES `Person` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `Person` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `Person` VALUES (1,4,'1944-07-21 00:00:00','male','Joe Smith','0',1,1),...,(10000,0,'2009-09-10 00:00:00','female','Stephanie Rebecca','9999',10000,10000);
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `Person` ENABLE KEYS */;
```

Two important sections in this file:

- `CREATE TABLE` gives us all column titles
- `INSERT INTO` are our data

In a real backup with much more data than that, you will probably have more than one single `INSERT INTO` line.

We basically need here to ignore the first 108 lines of our backup at first.

Let's look then at the first line:

```
cat person.sql | head -109 | tail -1
```

Gives:

```
INSERT INTO `Person` VALUES (1,4,'1944-07-21 00:00:00','male','Joe Smith','0',1,1),...,(10000,0,'2009-09-10 00:00:00','female','Stephanie Rebecca','9999',10000,10000);
```

### Read it with logstash

What we need to do here is to split each line with the following pattern:

```
INSERT INTO `Person` VALUES (DATA),(DATA),***,(DATA);
```

We can create a `mysql.conf` for logstash to parse this. As usual, start with an "empty" one:

```
input { stdin {} }

filter {
}

output { stdout { codec => rubydebug } }
```

Then, let's ignore the `INSERT INTO ...` part and extract the data in a new field named `extracted_sql`. Let's use a [grok filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html) for that:

```
grok {
  match => {
    "message" => "INSERT INTO \`Person\` VALUES (%{GREEDYDATA:extracted_sql})"
  }
  remove_field => "message"
}
```

Execute it:

```
cat person.sql | head -109 | tail -1 | bin/logstash -f mysql.conf
```

It gives something like this:

```
{
         "@version" => "1",
       "@timestamp" => "2015-09-14T07:32:43.495Z",
             "host" => "MacBook-Air-de-David.local",
    "extracted_sql" => "(..),..(..);
}
```

We now need to split `extracted_sql` in multiple events. Let's add a [split filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-split.html):

```
split {
  terminator => "),("
  field => "extracted_sql"
}
```

Launch again and it now gives one event per table line:

```
{
         "@version" => "1",
       "@timestamp" => "2015-09-14T07:38:34.489Z",
             "host" => "MacBook-Air-de-David.local",
    "extracted_sql" => "1,4,'1944-07-21 00:00:00','male','Joe Smith','0',1,1"
}
// ...
{
         "@version" => "1",
       "@timestamp" => "2015-09-14T07:37:25.729Z",
             "host" => "MacBook-Air-de-David.local",
    "extracted_sql" => "8906,3,'1958-12-17 00:00:00','male','Gautier Titouan','8905',8906,8906"
}
// ...
{
         "@version" => "1",
       "@timestamp" => "2015-09-14T07:38:34.489Z",
             "host" => "MacBook-Air-de-David.local",
    "extracted_sql" => "10000,0,'2009-09-10 00:00:00','female','Stephanie Rebecca','9999',10000,10000"
}
```

Sounds like we have now a CSV structure... We can either use a [CSV filter](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-csv.html) or a [GROK filter](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html).

Grok gives more flexibility because it helps to define the right data type you want for each field. The CSV filter can not directly do it [at the moment](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-filter-csv/pull/7). Grok can do it but it's based on regular expressions and it's a way slower than the CSV filter which is optimized to parse CSV content. So I'm trading here flexibility and ease to use for performance.

```
csv {
  source => "extracted_sql"
  quote_char => "'"
  columns => [ "id", 
    "children", "dateOfBirth", "gender", "name", 
    "reference", "address_id", "marketing_id" ]
  remove_field => "extracted_sql"
}
```

### Deal with NULL

If you have to deal with `NULL` values, just add before the CSV filter:

```
mutate {
    gsub => [
      "extracted_sql", "NULL", ""
    ]
}
```

### Select a timestamp

We also have some dates in various formats:

```
   "@timestamp" => "2015-09-14T07:38:34.489Z",
  "dateOfBirth" => "2009-09-10 00:00:00"
```

`dateOfBirth` is obviously the creation date. `@timestamp` is as always the internal logstash timestamp. We want `dateOfBirth` to become our event date.

```
date {
    match => [ "dateOfBirth", "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss" ]
    remove_field => "dateOfBirth"
}
```

### Drop the header

Nice so far. But what about the header part?

Well we have our first `grok` pattern which tries to parse `INSERT ...` so if it fails, it will generate a `_grokparsefailure` tag. We can drop each line which contains that:

```
# Just after the grok filter
if "_grokparsefailure" in [tags] {
  drop { }
}
```

We can now run our logstash configuration on the full file:

```
cat person.sql | bin/logstash -f mysql.conf
```

### Cleanup

We output for now:

```
{
        "@version" => "1",
      "@timestamp" => "1967-01-17T23:00:00.000Z",
            "host" => "MacBook-Air-de-David.local",
              "id" => "9999",
        "children" => "1",
          "gender" => "female",
            "name" => "Laetitia Lois",
       "reference" => "9998",
      "address_id" => "9999",
    "marketing_id" => "9999"
}
```

We don't need to keep `@version` and `host` fields:

```
mutate {
  remove_field => [ "@version", "host" ]
}
```

It gives:

```
{
      "@timestamp" => "1967-01-17T23:00:00.000Z",
              "id" => "9999",
        "children" => "1",
          "gender" => "female",
            "name" => "Laetitia Lois",
       "reference" => "9998",
      "address_id" => "9999",
    "marketing_id" => "9999"
}
```

## Connect to elasticsearch

Not the hardest part. But may be because I'm practicing elasticsearch for almost 5 years :)!

For new comers, you have to:

- [download](https://www.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch). 1.7.1 was the latest at this moment.
- unzip: `tar xzf elasticsearch-1.7.1.tar.gz`
- install [marvel](https://www.elastic.co/products/marvel/): `bin/plugin install elasticsearch/marvel/latest`
- launch: `bin/elasticsearch`

And connect logstash...

```
output {
  elasticsearch {
    host => "localhost"
    port => "9200"
    protocol => "http"
    index => "persons-%{+YYYY}"
    document_type => "person"
    document_id => "%{id}"
    template => "person.json"
    template_name => "person"
  }

  stdout {
    codec => "dots"
  }
}
```

Note that we send documents grouped by year in an index named `persons-YEAR4DIGITS`, using type `person` and with the original `id` as the document `_id`.

`person.json` file contains our template. We define that we use 1 single shard, that we don't need `_all` field and some other settings:

```
{
  "template": "persons-*",
  "order":    1, 
  "settings": {
    "number_of_shards": 1 
  },
  "mappings": {
    "_default_" : {
       "_all" : {"enabled" : false},
       "dynamic_templates" : [ {
         "string_fields" : {
           "match" : "*",
           "match_mapping_type" : "string",
           "mapping" : {
             "type" : "string", "index" : "analyzed", "omit_norms" : true,
               "fields" : {
                 "raw" : {"type": "string", "index" : "not_analyzed", "ignore_above" : 256}
               }
           }
         }
       } ]
    },
    "person": { 
      "properties": {
        "id": {
          "type": "long",
          "index": "no"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Launch!

```
cat person.sql | bin/logstash -f mysql.conf
```

If you want to increase the injection rate, just add more workers to logstash:

```
cat person.sql | bin/logstash -f mysql.conf -w 2
```